# Zend 2 EventManager listen only to a specific Module

Tags: events, zend-framework2

I Have a Zend 2 application with a admin module. I want my admin users to have different access to admin panel, so I used ACL. In order to do that I create a different module Authorize where I create an Event Lister like bellow:

```
$application = $e->getApplication();
$em = $application->getEventManager();
$em->attach('route', array($this, 'onRoute'), -100);

public function onRoute(\Zend\EventManager\EventInterface $e) 
{ 
  // DO STUFF HERE
}
```

The question is: is there a possibility to attach this event only to routes on my Admin module?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you can just look at the documentation and work this out...

https://github.com/bjyoungblood/BjyAuthorize

You'd just need to add a line like this to your auth config

```
        \BjyAuthorize\Guard\Route::class => [
            ['route' => 'admin', 'roles' => ['admin']],
        ],
```

Or am I misunderstanding what you mean by "different access"?